# @CacheResult in combination with default interface method call

Tags: java, caching, jakarta-ee, hazelcast, jcache

I have a `JavaEE` WebApp using `jCache` abstraction. Given I have an interface like this:

```
public interface Service {

    default ReturnObject getReturnObject(String userId) {
        return getReturnObject(userId, null);
    }

    ReturnObject getReturnObject(String userId, String customerId);

}
```

And its implementation as follows:

```
public class ServiceImpl {

    @Override
    @CacheResult(cacheName = CACHE_NAME, cacheKeyGenerator = DefaultObjectsCacheKeyGenerator.class)
    public ReturnObject getReturnObject(@CacheKey String userId, @CacheKey String customerId) {
...

    }
}
```

Can I expect the caching functionality to work properly, i.e. when the default method is getting called with one argument, then the caching will kick in with `null` as the second half of the cache key? I'm worried about something similar to what happens in a Spring proxy where in-class method calls are not proxied and hence no caching/transactioning stuff happens.

Any clues?